# How to send large no of parameters with post request

Tags: post

Currently, I need send large no of user input parameters to the servlet. (more then 5000) But my ajax post request is giving 400 error bad request header too long.
How to handle this?

I'm taking all user entered parts as an array and passing as below:

```
var url = "/bin/maxim/legacy/tradecompliance?partNum="+ encodeURIComponent(array);
```

Comment: I suggest checking web server's config for maximum post values.

Comment: Do you have any control over the backend? If yes, then instead of sending the params as a query string, you can use post body. Let me know if this is an option, ill give you an example

Comment: Aravindan: yes I've control over the backend. Please suggest an example to know how to send using post body.

Comment: Got this done by passing data in post body.